# spring boot, data is present in the database but the query is resulting null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

the interface ***CompanyMasterInterface***:

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value ="SELECT s.* from companymaster as s WHERE s.name = ':title'")
    public CompanyMaster ByNameOrDaName(@Param("title") String title);
```

the service ***CompanyMasterServiceImpl***:

```
  @Autowired
  private CompanyMasterInterface services;

  public CompanyMaster ByNameOrDaName(String title) {
    return services.ByNameOrDaName(title);
 }
```

Controller:
for example the name is 'Taj' and it's present in the database.

```
   @Autowired
   private CompanyMasterServiceImpl companyImpl;

   ////now the class is as following

   CompanyMaster cmp = companyImpl.ByNameOrDaName("Taj");
   
   if(cmp == null){
      System.out.println("there is no data");
   } else {
      System.out.println("there is data");
   }
```

the problem is why always i get that the {cmp is null} while the Taj is there in the database.

Comment: I'm surprised the code you posted even compiles. 'Taj' is not valid Java

Comment: it's update, "", because I use to pass this dynamic so I forgot to correct it while posting

Comment: remove single quote around `:title`

Comment: yes that's correct, we both got it in same time lol

Answer (score 0):

The "`SELECT s.* from companymaster as s WHERE s.name = ':title`" isn't correct, you ought to use "`CompanyMaster` ", not "`companymaster` ".

Comment: the correct query is you don't have to user (') with :title 
{   SELECT s.* from companymaster as s WHERE s.name = :title } that must be query like